# How to call previous date record?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as following

```
===========================
+---------+----------+--------
ACC_NUM    DATE      BALANCE
+---------+----------+--------
A101         01-01-19     120 
+---------+----------+--------
A101         02-01-19     100 
+---------+----------+--------
A101         03-01-19      90 
+---------+----------+--------
```

I want output as following:

```
==========================
+---------+----------+--------,--------------,
ACC_NUM   . DATE     . BALANCE' PEV_DATE_BAL '
+---------+----------+--------'--------------'
A101       01-01-19        120               '
---------------------------------------------'
A101       02-01-19        100           120 '
---------------------------------------------'
A101       03-01-19         90           100 '
----------------------------------------------
```

What query can output as following?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the LAG function:

```
SELECT ACC_NUM
       , DATE_c
       , BALANCE
       , LAG(BALANCE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_c) PEV_DATE_BAL
FROM testTable;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f688a08300e8872bbeb5e956f38c4ba)

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. Please can you mark this answer as correct and give it a vote up. Thanks!